# Java Read file to multiple classes throws error

Tags: java, file, class

I need to read in data from a file to a class, the problem I have is that I cannot figure a way to do it, I need to get the data from the first line and assign it to one class and then get the data from the rest of the lines and assign them to another class. I receive this error in the attached image, I cannot understand why is cannot convert the string to an int? I have added a comment on which line is the issue.

```
public class Album {
    private String title, artist;
    private int year;
    private double sales;
    private List<Track> tracks;

    public Album(String title, String artist, int year, double sales) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.year = year;
        this.sales = sales;
        tracks = new ArrayList<>();
    }


public class Track {
    private String title;
    private int minute, seconds;
    
    public Track(String title, int minute, int seconds) {
        this.title = title;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }



 public List<Album> getAlbums() {
    List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();
    String dataFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "albums.txt";

    Scanner input = null;

    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File(dataFile));

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String line = input.nextLine().trim();
            String[] bits = line.split(":");
            int index = 0;

            if (bits.length > 3) {
                index = Integer.parseInt(bits[0].trim()) - 1; // Line 28 
                int year = Integer.parseInt(bits[3].trim());
                albums.add(new Album(bits[1], bits[2], year, bits[4]));
            } else if (bits.length == 2) {
                String title = removeLastCharacters(bits[0]);
                int minute = Integer.parseInt(bits[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                int seconds = Integer.parseInt(bits[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                albums.get(index).addTrack(new Track(title, minute, seconds));
            } else {
                input.next();
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("Cannot locate file.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return albums;
}

private String removeLastCharacters(String str) {
    String result = null;
    if ((str != null) && (str.length() > 0)) {
        result = str.substring(0, str.length() - 3);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIOEO.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbvVh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error scenario:

1. `input.nextLine()` reads the first album delimiter `---------------------`.
2. `input.next()` reads only `2:Different`.
3. `input.nextLine()` reads `Class:Pulp:1996:1.33M`.
4. `Integer.parseInt("Class")` throws exception.

You should change

```
        } else {
            input.next();
        }
```

to

```
        }
```

And also change

```
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        .....
        int index = 0;
        .....
    }
```

to

```
    int index = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        .....
    }
```

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you. The albums are now being added correctly but the tracks for them are not, they are all being added to the first album at index 0, I tried to change the code to index++ but still the same result, why is it not updating?

Comment: @Radkata I added it to the answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, every time it irritates trough the loop it, it makes it 0, thank you a lot!